# Downloading Images from list of URL to server using PHP

Tags: php, curl, foreach

I made a simple script that can download image from the URL. It perfectly works.

```
$img_link = 'https://samplesite.com/image.jpg';
$imge_title = basename($img_link);


$ch = curl_init($img_link);
$fp = fopen("folder/".$imge_title, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The next thing to is to Download a list of URLS from a txt file and process them per line.

```
https://samplesite.com/image_1.jpg
https://samplesite.com/image_2.jpg
https://samplesite.com/image_3.jpg
https://samplesite.com/image_4.jpg
https://samplesite.com/image_5.jpg
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
$lines = file( 'List.txt' ); //the list of image URLs

foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
$img_link = $line;
$imge_title = basename($img_link); //I want to retain the original name of the file


$ch = curl_init($img_link);
$fp = fopen($imge_title, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
}
```

It doesn't work and I keep getting Warnings:

```
Warning: fopen(image_1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Comment: It's probably because of the line break character at the end of `$imge_title`.

Comment: Im sorry, I think Im not getting what that "line break" is.

Comment: So you did not read the manual for `file` then? Go do that now.

Comment: `file line failed to open stream: No such file or directory` . Add directory in here `$imge_title = basename($img_link);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As the `file` doc says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), the file's newlines are preserved in the resulting array:

> Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached.**

Pass the [`FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to the `file(...)` call.

Otherwise, most or all of your `$line` values will end with a `'\n'` or `'\r'` character.

You should probably also pass `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`.

```php
$lines = file( 'List.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ); //the list of image URLs
```